# Image don't appear In my App

Tags: image, xaml

I make an Windows8App and unfortunately some image don't want us to see them.
I give you some **XAML**

```
       <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
                            <RowDefinition />
                            <RowDefinition Height="3*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="26">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="26"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <!-- THIS ONE DOES NOT SHOW -->
                            <Image Source="..\Assets\picto_mes_question.png" Grid.Column="0" Height="26" Width="26"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Width="150">
                                <TextBlock  Text="Modèle de Questions" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="12" Margin="0"  
                                        Foreground="{StaticResource BlueAppBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                        <!-- THIS ONE DOES NOT SHOW -->
                        <Image VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="1" Source="..\Assets\white-line.png" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="20"/>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="2" Width="170">
                            <TextBlock Text="Voici une partie de la question de test qui doit faire moins d'un certain nombre de caractère a l'affichage mais pas dans le contenus final qui serra afficher une foi cliqué." 
                                   MaxLines="2" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light" Foreground="{StaticResource BlueAppBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" LineHeight="12" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="10" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
```

When I load my page, every other image on the UserControl (yes it's on a userControl) Appear normally. Exepte one other image, I guess it's the same error.

```
    <Setter.Value>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Image Source="..\Assets\close.png" Height="20" Width="20"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
```

I you find something for me, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

The VS autolink past a link with a backslash. You need a slash.

**Wrong**

```
<Image Source="..\Assets\close.png" Height="20" Width="20"/>
```

**Correct**

```
<Image Source="../Assets/close.png" Height="20" Width="20"/>
```